# how can I make diagonal lines with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a diagonal line with CSS, like the following image, but I have no idea how to do it.
[image: screen]

Could you guide me how to do it?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #632878;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 160%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
  transform: rotate(55deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content... -->
</div>
```

Comment: use straight lines and rotate your element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider multiple background. Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top right,   transparent 49.5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%) 50% calc(50% + 60px/2 + 80px/2)/100% 80px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%) 50% calc(50% - 60px/2 - 120px/2)/100% 120px,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) center/100% 60px,
    
    linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Or clip path like below:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
}
.container::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  bottom:50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 31%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
   clip-path: polygon(0 31%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Another idea with rotation and perspective:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:140px;
  bottom:120px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transform:perspective(200px) rotateY(-25deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I like the variety of implementations provided.

Comment: @Temani Afif  You could indicate me some place where I can document or learn a little about that part or some tool to do the calculation.

Comment: @Vision there is no tools to do the calculation it's all manually done ... basically you simply need to understand how properties works and you will be able to adjust the values to obtain what you want. you can find everything here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web .. the only tool that may help you with the clip path is this one https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/